# Django REST serialize field group by date

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

**Problem: Not able to group my JSON output by date**

**SOLUTION IN BOTTOM OF THIS POST**

I am serializing a model and getting this output:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-11-24",
        "name": "Chest",
        "workout": {
            "name": "Chest",
            "exercise": 1,
            "repetitions": 10,
            "weight": 80
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-11-24",
        "name": "Chest",
        "workout": {
            "name": "Chest",
            "exercise": 1,
            "repetitions": 10,
            "weight": 85
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-11-24",
        "name": "Chest",
        "workout": {
            "name": "Chest",
            "exercise": 1,
            "repetitions": 10,
            "weight": 90
        }
    },
```

I want to get it like the JSON below and group it by **date**.

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-11-24",
        "workout": {
            "name": "Chest",
            "exercise": 1,
            "repetitions": 10,
            "weight": 80
        },
            "name": "Chest",
            "exercise": 1,
            "repetitions": 10,
            "weight": 85
        },
            "name": "Chest",
            "exercise": 1,
            "repetitions": 10,
            "weight": 90
        },
    }
]
```

I have one model:

```
class WorkoutLog(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) #When save() name = Workout.name
    exercise = models.ForeignKey('Exercise', related_name='log', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    repetitions = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()
```

Trying to serialize and group the JSON by date:

```
class WorkoutLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkoutLog
        fields = ['date', 'workout']
    
    workout = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_workout')

    def get_workout(self, obj):
        return {
            'name': obj.name,
            'exercise': obj.exercise_id,
            'repetitions': obj.repetitions,
            'weight': obj.weight,
        }
```

The code lets me custom the field layout, but not really grouping it by date. Do you have any suggestions on how to structure it?

Many thanks for all help!

in case its needed, here is my view.py

```
def workout_log(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        workout_log = WorkoutLog.objects.all()
        serializer = WorkoutLogSerializer(workout_log, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

**SOLUTION BY Mahmoud Adel:**

views.py

```
def workout_log(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        workout_log = WorkoutLog.objects.order_by('date').values('date').distinct()
        serializer = WorkoutLogSerializer(workout_log, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

serializers.py

```
class WorkoutFieldSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      name = serializers.CharField()
      #exercise = serializers.IntegerField()
      repetitions = serializers.IntegerField()
      weight = serializers.IntegerField()
      
class WorkoutLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkoutLog
        fields = ['date', 'workout']
    
    workout = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_workout')

    def get_workout(self, obj):
        workouts = WorkoutLog.objects.filter(date=obj['date'])
        workout_serializer = WorkoutFieldSerializer(workouts, many=True)
        return workout_serializer.data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

Let's start first with your view, I will tweak the queryset like that

```
def workout_log(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        workout_log = WorkoutLog.objects.order_by('date').distinct('date').only('date')
        serializer = WorkoutLogSerializer(workout_log, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Then on your `WorkoutLogSerializer`

```
class WorkoutLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkoutLog
        fields = ['date', 'workout']
    
    workout = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_workout')

    def get_workout(self, obj):
        workouts = WorkoutLog.objects.filter(date=obj.date)
        workout_serializer = WorkoutSerializer(workouts, many=True)
        return workout_serializer.data
```

And finally, create `WorkoutSerializer`

```
class WorkoutSerializer(serializers.Serializers):
      name = serializers.CharField()
      exercise = serializers.IntegerField()
      repetitions = serializers.IntegerField()
      weight = serializers.IntegerField()
```

The previous way will first be got to the DB to get the `distinct` dates then on `WorkoutLogSerializer` will use each date to select the corresponding objects that have it, then we serialize those objects.

We get the intended result by doing so, note that this will **result** in `2 DB hits`, there may be another way that will do it in one DB hit, I will update my answer if I have figured it out

**NOTE**: I have written this to explain the flow and the logic I didn't run it, although it should work I may forget something that will show an error for you, feel free to try it.

UPDATE: check this answer comments if you are using SQLite.

Comment: Hi Mahnoud, thank you for taking the time to help. I tried your suggestion, which got me this error:
`django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend` 

I have tried to change the views to: 
`workout_log = WorkoutLog.objects.order_by('date').values_list('date', flat=True).distinct()` 
after some tips on web, but then get this error. 

`AttributeError The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'date' instance.
Original exception text was: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'.`

Comment: this happened because of `flat=True`, as it will only return data and drop mapping it to field name `date`, that's why the serializer raise attribute error too, remove `flat=true` it should work, `workout_log = WorkoutLog.objects.order_by('date').values_list('date').distinct()`

Comment: So I have tried different things now and willl no luck. When I use ```workout_log = WorkoutLog.objects.order_by('date').values_list('date').distinct()``` I will get error: "Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'date"

Comment: If I use ```workout_log = WorkoutLog.objects.order_by('date').values('date').distinct()``` I will get error: "workouts = WorkoutLog.objects.filter(date=obj.date)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'date'"

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: the error you got on serializer because it returns a `ValuesQuerySet` which behaves differently from a `QuerySet`. When you access says, the first element of `workout_log`  you'll get a dictionary, NOT an instance of WorkoutLog.

Comment: so in `get_workout`, we need to modify it a little bit, it should be `workouts = WorkoutLog.objects.filter(date=obj['date'])`

Comment: I really really appreciate you taking the time to help and explain everything properly. it worked now!! Many thanks! I used at least 5 hours trying to figure it out. I just started learning Django 4 weeks ago, so its going quite slow... Again THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem at all, I'm glad that you find my answers clear and helpful :), it may be quite slow at the beginning when learning Django, but things and problems like this will make you learn more. my recommendation is to be friends with the docs, also using SQLite is intended for quick development but for almost any real-world app you will use another DB so don't be distracted by SQLite things. and finally, feel free to get in touch here if you have more questions

Comment: Just one more quesiton. What I want 'date' AND 'name' to be unique? Currently, I am not able to just add 'name' to the fields list. if I just add 'name' to fields =  ['date', 'name', 'workout'] I get:

Comment: ```KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `WorkoutLogSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'name'."```

Comment: this happens because as we talked before we right now having a `ValuesQuerySet` not `QuerySet` so this is not a `WorkoutLog`instance anymore, in order to get it to work remove `values('date')` and follow the code snippet in the answer