# Group by in serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

In Django Rest Framework, I want to group my serializer data by date, How can I do that.

I have to group it by date on the basis of timestamp date.

my model: mongo model with some more fields also but only uses these two fields

```
class MyModel(Document):
    #mongo model
    
    candidate_id = StringField(required=True, db_field='c')
    timestamp = DateTimeField(required=True, db_field='d')
    ... 
    ... more fields
```

My Views: my views file

```
class MyView(generics.ListAPIView): 
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        recruiter_id = self.request.GET.get("recruiter_id")
        activity_list = MyModel.objects.filter(recruiter_id=str(recruiter_id)).order_by('-     timestamp')
        return activity_list
```

my serializer: using serializermethod field to get data from other DB by using candidate id from activity model

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    
    candidate_id = serializers.CharField()
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    designation = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    age = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%H:%M")


    def get_name(self, obj):
        return something

    def get_designation(self, obj):
        return something
        
    def get_age(self, obj):
        return something
```

I want to group my response by Date like :

```
[
{
    "date": "2022-12-05",
    "candidates":[
      {
        "candidate_id": 1,
        "name": "One",
        "designation": "Lead",
        "age": 30,
        "timestamp": "14:30"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-12-04",
    "candidates":[
      {
        "candidate_id": 2,
        "name": "Two",
        "designation": "Lead",
        "age": 30,
        "timestamp": "14:30",
      }
    ]
    
  }
]
```

my actual response is like:

```
[
  {
      "candidate_id": 1,
      "name": "One",
      "designation": "Lead",
      "age": 30,
      "activity_timestamp": "13:12"
  },
  {
      "candidate_id": 2,
      "name": "Two",
      "designation": "Lead",
      "age": 30,
      "activity_timestamp": "13:12"
  }
]
```

Comment: I don't think there is built-in way of doing it in DRF, you'd have to write the aggregation yourself in the view.

Comment: [might be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995344/django-rest-serialize-field-group-by-date)